# How to get dynamic year wise data in mysql pivot table

Tags: mysql

I want to get year wise data in MySQL pivot table.I have one table

```
id | Name  | Amount | Date    
1  | ABC   | 50     | 2018-05-16    
2  | PQR   | 60     | 2017-07-16    
3  | LMN   | 40     | 2017-01-16
```

I want result Like

```
Type  | 2018 | 2017
total |   1  |  2  
SUM   |   50 | 100
```

Also date column values should be dynamic. If new year date is entered,The pivot table should contain that year i.e. if date value is 2019-01-22 then pivot table will show 2019 as column

Comment: In what way would the year be dynamic? Do you only want the last 2 years based on current year ,or the last 2 years based on a supplied year or something else?

Comment: No, I want all years as per date values are present in table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: A little different to the usual mysql row to columns in that are going to have to union 2 queries 1 for the total/count row and 1 for the sum row.

Comment: how is it possible ??